# How to find and plot gradient of multiple variables at a given point?

Tags: python, python-3.x, math, gradient

I found gradient of function but I don't know how to plot graph.

```
import numdifftools as nd

def rosen(xy): 
    return (xy[0]**2 + xy[1])

grad = nd.Gradient(rosen)([2, 4])
print("Gradient of is ", grad)
```

Comment: What graph? Explain the expected output.

Comment: I need to calculate the gradient of a multivariable function and draw a graph of the gradient and I do not know how to do the graph